# Declare and implement pure virtual destructor in one line?

Tags: c++, abstract-class, virtual-destructor

I am making a pure virtual destructor to force a class to be abstract that contains no methods apart from the ctor. I am doing this as a header-only implementation

```
struct abstractSchema
{
    abstractSchema(...): ... { ... }
    virtual ~abstractSchema() = 0;    
};
inline abstractSchema::~abstractSchema(){}
```

Is there any syntactic sugar like (the illegal) `virtual ~abstractSchema(){} = 0;` that would allow me to declare and define on a single line, rather than having to split the definition and implementation like in the above example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is as close as you can get:

```
struct abstractSchema
{
    virtual ~abstractSchema(){}
    protected: abstractSchema(...): ... { ... }
};
```

It's not abstract, but it can't be instantiated by itself so might meet your needs.

Answer (score -1):

You can:

```
struct abstractSchema
{
    virtual ~abstractSchema() = 0 {}
};
```

Not sure about standard-compliant compilers, but MSVC (2010) compiles this code just fine.

Comment: @Fanael You can appellate to Microsoft. I know gcc doesn't compile it. Microsoft Visual C++ does.

Comment: -1: Question asked about C++, not some specific implementation's extensions. You can have a symbolic +1 for being right, though.